# Calling popup image gallery from infobox?

Tags: javascript, popup, image-gallery

In my blog folder I have two subfolders: map and gallery. Map has an interactive city map with restaurant icons, and gallery has an image subfolder for each restaurant. Each restaurant’s image folder currently contain two additional files: ‘get_images.php’ that creates an image array from the folder’s contents, and ‘index.html’ that generates a gallery from that array. I can call a popup image gallery for each restaurant from an infobox on the map, using:

```
boxText.innerHTML="<a href='javascript:popUp("+'"../gallery/'+restaurant+'/index.html"'+")'>gallery</a><br/>"
```

where the ‘restaurant’ variable is pulled from a mySql database and 'popUp' is a function that creates the popup.

This is cumbersome, and I'd like to eliminate the need to have the get_images.php and index.html files in every single restaurant folder. I can put the get_images.php anywhere and call it from the main script, but I'm struggling to find a way to call the rotate_images() function that resides in index.html in a popup window. Here's the function:

```
var curimg=0
function rotate_images(){
document.getElementById("gallery").setAttribute("src", ""+galleryarray[curimg])
curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}
```

I've tried

```
"<a href=   'javascript:rotate_images(" + '"' + '../gallery/pizzahut/files/' + galleryarray[curimg] + '"' + ")'>gallery</a><br/>";
```

which shows 'javascript:rotate_images("../gallery/pizzahut/files/pizzahut1.jpg")' when I hover over the link, but nothing when I click on it. I'm assuming it's because I haven't included an 'img id' tag, but I don't know where to put it to indicate a popup. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put your function `rotate_images` in a file called `map.js` for instance.
Then include this file in any html page that need the function.

Example :

**index.html**

```
<head>
<!-- include map.js here -->
<script src="path/to/map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
(...)
<a href="#" onclick='javascript:rotate_images(" + '"' + '../gallery/pizzahut/files/' + galleryarray[curimg] + '"' + ");return false'>gallery</a><br/>
(...)
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, Stephan. I'll make the necessary changes and get back to you. One question: does there needs to be an id tag somewhere in the href line for this part of the rotate_images function to work? `document.getElementById("gallery").setAttribute("src", "../images/"+galleryarray[curimg])`

Comment: @2nu2no the id is not required

Comment: OK, I've used the process you suggest, with the following results:

Comment: Try again - got caught by the 5 minute edit rule. Results are that the .php file is creating the image array, the .js file is receiving the array and passing it to the main .html file (I've checked with an alert box) BUT I'm getting an error message when I click on the href link- "TypeError: document.getElementById("slideshow") is null". I can only think that the lack of reference to "slideshow" in the main file is causing a problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check that you have an element in the html page with id='slideshow'